# Excel to .csv problem

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have an excel file that i need to get into CSV. I export it fine but when I go to import it into a mysql db via phpMyAdmin i get a "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.".

Problem seems to be that the fields are not enclosed by double quotes.  I just migrated to MS Excel 2007 and am not sure how to manipulate the CSV save options so that there are double quotes around the fields so my DB doesn't throw a conniption when i try to import.

Any suggestions?  I'm fairly new at going from EXCEL to CSV but have gotten it to work previously.

Thanks

Comment: This is a MySQL question so I retagged your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after exporting from Excel as CSV and defining various options

```
load data infile '/tmp/tc_t.csv' 
into table new_test_categories 
fields terminated by ','    
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
ignore 1 lines 
(id,category_name,type_id,home_collection,seo_tags,status_id);
```

I ran this at the mysql prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an MS-DOS format of CSV in your export drop down. Pick that one.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in save-as advanced properties or something, but if not, you could always change the delimiter character to : or ; or | and then write a quick perl script to convert it to a quote-and-comma file.

Or you could just try a tab-separated-value file instead, I think phpMyAdmin will read TSVs as well.